# let define the "waved" factorial as $\prod_{i=1}^n (\text{if } \bmod(i,2)=={0\text{ or } 1}\text{ then } [2/i] \text{ else } [i])$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, pi, infinite-product

Consider these two products:

EvenWavedFactorial = $$\prod_{i=1}^n \text{if } (i\bmod 2 ==0)\text{ then } \left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \text{ else }(i)$$
OddWavedFactorial  = $$\prod_{i=1}^n \text{ if } (i\bmod2==1)\text{ then } \left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \text{ else } (i)$$

the  sum of the reciprocal partial sums of EvenWavedFactorial $\,\cong\, \pi + 1$

$$\sum_{j=1}^k \left(\prod_{i=1}^j [\text{if } (i\bmod 2==0)\text{ then } \left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \text{ else }(\ i\ )]\right)^{-1} \cong \pi + 1$$

the  sum of the reciprocal partial sums of OddWavedFactorial $\,\cong\, 2\sqrt2-1$

$$\sum_{j=1}^k \left(\prod_{i=1}^j [\text{ if } (i\bmod 2==1)\text{ then } \left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \text{ else }(\ i\ )]\right)^{-1} \cong 2\sqrt2-1$$

We need to **set k = 100** to reach a good precision (~12 decimals)

`Here below the output of a test program:
____________factorialAlternateEven(1..100) ~ π + 1$ 
bf_sum    : 4.141592653589781694678858471900
pi + 1    : 4.141592653589793238462643383280
delta     : 0.000000000000011543783784911380`

`____________factorialAlternateOdd(1..100) ~ 2 √2 - 1
bf_sum    : 1.828427124746182819286454719580
2*sqr(2)-1: 1.828427124746190097603377448419
delta     : 0.000000000000007278316922728839`

[image: The 20 first values of these "waved" factorials]

`The 20 first values of these "waved" factorials`

As you can see these "waved" factorials grow slowly and alternate somehow as a sinusoid.

**Questions**:

- how can it be explained that the sum of "even waved factorial" is about pi + 1?
- how can it be explained that the sum of "odd waved factorial" is about 2 * sqrt(2) - 1?
- it could be linked with the double-factorial function, but I am not able to find the trick.

Comment: Both questions you've posted express the sums in a way useful for computers, but not mathematics. Your sums above are more akin to a program in C than a mathematics problem. My advice is the same in both posts: split the product up to remove modulo and study the resulting products.

Comment: Your MathJax usage was a mess. Please look at the cleanups that were done. Including proper use of \text{}.

Comment: Note that $a \mod 2$ isn't mathematics notation. What you are looking for is $a \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$

Comment: Is your $\left(\dfrac2i\right)$ supposed to be division? There are several other things that use very similar notation and it would be good to clarify - an example or two would work wonders here.

Comment: Note that your first sum can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+1}{k} \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{n}{2n-1} \to \pi +1$

Answer (score 0):

here below the julia program that i used:

`function EvenWavedFactorial(bi_Max::Int64 )::BigFloat
 bf_factalt = BigFloat(1.0)
 bi_n = BigInt(0)
 for bi_n = 1:bi_Max
    if (mod(bi_n, 2) == 0)
       bf_factalt *= BigFloat(2.0 / bi_n)   #same as: #bf_factalt /= BigFloat(bi_n / 2.0)
    else
       bf_factalt *= BigFloat(bi_n)
    end
 end
 return bf_factalt
end`

function OddWavedFactorial(bi_Max::Int64 )::BigFloat
 bf_factalt = BigFloat(1.0)
 bi_n = BigInt(0)
 for bi_n = 1:bi_Max
    if (mod(bi_n, 2) == 1)
       bf_factalt *= BigFloat(2.0 / bi_n)   #same as: bf_factalt /= BigFloat(bi_n / 2.0)
    else
       bf_factalt *= BigFloat(bi_n)
    end
 end
 return bf_factalt
end

println("----------------------------------------------------------------")
println(string(">>>> starting at ", now()))
println("----------------------------------------------------------------")

bi_n   = Int64(0)
bf_sum = BigFloat(0.0)
bf_res = BigFloat(0.0)

for bi_n = 1:100  # the cumulative sum of EvenWavedFactorial trending to : π + 1
    bf_res = 1.0 / EvenWavedFactorial(bi_n)
    bf_sum += bf_res
end

println("EvenWavedFactorial(1..100)  ==> π + 1")
println("-----------------------------------------")
@printf("bf_sum    : %32.30f", bf_sum)
print('\n')
@printf("pi + 1    : %32.30f", BigFloat(pi) + 1)
print('\n')
@printf("delta     : %32.30f", BigFloat(pi) + 1 - bf_sum)
print('\n')
println("==================================================================================")

bf_sum = BigFloat(0.0)   ## reset the cumulative sum - the cumulative sum of OddWavedFactorial trending to : 2√(2)-1
for bi_n = 1:100
    bf_res = 1.0 / OddWavedFactorial(bi_n)
    bf_sum += bf_res
end

println("OddWavedFactorial(1..100)  ==> 2 √2 - 1")
println("-------------------------------------------")
@printf("bf_sum    : %32.30f", bf_sum)
print('\n')
@printf("2*sqr(2)-1: %32.30f", BigFloat(2.0) * BigFloat(sqrt(BigFloat(2.0, 64))) - BigFloat(1.0) )
print('\n')
@printf("delta     : %32.30f", BigFloat(2.0) * BigFloat(sqrt(BigFloat(2.0, 64))) - BigFloat(1.0) - bf_sum )
print('\n')
println("==================================================================================")
print('\n')

println("the first WavedFactorial Even and Odd values:")
println("---------------------------------------------")

frm_string = ""

for bi_n = 1:30
    frm_string = @sprintf("%s %2.0f", "n:", bi_n )
    frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %12.5f", " EvenWaved! : ", EvenWavedFactorial(bi_n)))

```
if mod(bi_n, 2) == 0
   frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %9.6f", "[x]", 2/bi_n))
else
   frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %9.6f", "[x]", bi_n))
end

frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %12.5f", " OddWaved! : ", OddWavedFactorial(bi_n)))

if mod(bi_n, 2) == 1
   frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %9.6f", "[x]", 2/bi_n))
else
   frm_string = string(frm_string, " ", @sprintf("%s %9.6f", "[x]", bi_n))
end

println(frm_string)
```

end

println("----------------------------------------------------------------")
println(string("<<<< ending at ", now()))
println("----------------------------------------------------------------")